# Call not yet defined Model's manager in predefined Model Method Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have 2 models:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Message(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='messages_sent', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='messages_recieved', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

Notice `Person` was defined before `Message`.

I can reference `Message` before it's definition in `Person` if I use a `ForeignKey` like so:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    myfield = models.ForeignKey('message', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

to call a not yet defined Model before definition.

But what's the best way to call a not yet defined Model in a previously defined Model's method?

**Example:**

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    myfield = models.ForeignKey('message', on_delete=models.CASCADE)  # First reference before definition

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def send_message(self, message, recipient):
        sent_message = Message.objects.create(sender=self, recipient=recipient, text=message)  # Second reference before definition in a method somehow?
        return sent_message


class Message(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='messages_sent', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='messages_recieved', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

Is there a way to do this without defining the Person model below the Message model?

If so, what'd be the best approach?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

This actually would work even with defining the model later down the line.

I'm not actually sure why I received an error before.

Comment: Did you get any errors, specifically ***`NameError: name 'Message' is not defined`*** while accessing **`Message.objects.create(...)`** inside the `send_message()` method?

Comment: Hmm, for some reason I did on a previous project but now it seems to be working normally when I did it in a test environment. It gave me the error  that was something like "Cannot use undefined Model Manager  before definition" or something like that.

Comment: Python will not evaluate that statement on the project starting time, hence there will not be any *NameError*, that's for sure.

Comment: Also, the ***`self.messages_sent`*** is the *related manager*, not *default manager*. By default, both are same, but, both can be different too

Comment: Yeah I even reset the database and actually what I have now above worked. I'm not sure how I previously received that error before hand unfortunately.  I literally received it yesterday on another project and found a workaround of putting the top model beneath the undefined model.

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out.

You can call an undefined ForeignKey model by it's related name.

In this case, I could do:

```
class Person(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150):

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def send_message(self, recipient, message):
        sent_message = self.messages_sent.create(recipient=recipient, text=message)  # "messages_sent" is the related name of the later defined "Message"'s ForeignKey
        return sent_message

class Message(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='messages_sent', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='messages_recieved', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```